# What is the best method for default selection on multi-select list component?

Tags: web-app, users, dashboard, management

We are using angular material multi-select component on sign up page.

1. User can select multiple options from the list of 4-5 whose scope can increase in future.
   Example : Location A,Location B ,Location C  ,Location D
2. User need to select one location  as default selection so that on login, he lands on the corresponding landing page of the location every-time.

How do we go about it ?

Comment: The multi-select component itself is a mandatory field in the form.

Comment: How about a dynamic dropdown list update with the selected options that is also a mandatory field in the form?

Comment: When they are signing up, what do the locations indicate? Is this an important selection, or is it more just for convenience for the user?

Comment: It is an important selection and it is mandatory for user to select. @maxathousand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One pattern I've seen (though not that often) is to **ask the user where they would like to go during the login**.

If it's not a critical option, this preference can simply be stored in a cookie on the client device. The next time I visit this login page, my preference is already selected.

[image: Log in form with a "Take Me To" dropdown]

<sup><sub>Taken from mohela.com, a loan provider.</sub></sup>

If, however, it *is* an important option to preserve with the user's account, a [dynamic select menu like @bracco23 described](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/131881/what-is-the-best-method-for-default-selection-on-multi-select-list-component#comment209542_131881) could work in the sign-up form. Be sure to also provide somewhere to update this selection later, perhaps near where the user can update their other sign in options.

<sub>See also [my answer on a related question (*How to present boolean options along with selecting exactly 1 of them as “primary”?*)](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/129956/how-to-present-boolean-options-along-with-selecting-exactly-1-of-them-as-primar/129958#129958).</sub>